# Session array resets on submit?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have **test.php**:

```
<html>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION))
{
    echo 'session is not yet set';
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['comments'] = array();
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
<input type="text" name="comment">
Click the button!
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php

array_push($_SESSION['comments'], $_GET['comment']);
echo 'Current array count: ' . count($_SESSION['comments']) . '<br>';

foreach($_SESSION['comments'] as $comm)
{
    echo $comm.'<br>';
}

?>
</html>
```

What should happen is that any text entered in the textbox should be pushed to the session array, but every time I click on submit, what is printed is the text I just entered instead of appending/storing the previous entries. I only get `1` as the array count all the time.

Every time I hit submit, `session is not yet set` always shows at the top of the page even when I have the if condition.

I can't seem to find what's wrong?

Comment: put session_start(); on the top of page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_start()` does not just start a NEW session. If the client already has a session it resumes that session. [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)
If you are using sessions, just have `session_start();` at the top of the page and PHP will do the lifting of starting or resuming a session.

Comment: I'll have this answer accepted in a few minutes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
<?php
 session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION))
{
?>
```

Otherwise you have header output from the HTML tag and the session can't start properly.

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers, so I'll just upvote this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should start the session at the top of the page always.

```
session_start(); //start the session
```

Then we can check session is exist or not.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
     // your code
    }else{
     // your code
    }
```